# Angular 2 output eventemitter

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to link a button's `(click)` event and `[disable]` state with a component, such that the component can `disable` the button and the click can trigger an action in the component. They sit next to each other in another component (loaded through a route...).

I could have an `Output()` event from the child component that triggered a function in the parent component to set a boolean which was passed to the button like this `<button [disabled]='isDisabled' />`...

This seems messy and tricky to keep on top of, especially if I need many similar things on a page... Is there a better way?

Comment: Passing data using `@output()` decorator from child component to its parent can get messy when parent -child tree is two or three level deep but you make a _communication service_ to make it simple and look better. Here is the Angular docs link for more details on [Parent and children communicate via a service.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create separate `@Output` property. Angular adds only one listener per dom node, i.e. if you have `@HostListener` and `(click)` there is still only one dom listener and it depends on order of execution whether you will be able to stop propagation or not. `@Output` property gives you full control over emitter.